# Does "$\lim_{s\rightarrow\infty}$ $f_s$ (x) exists a.e." imply that for $x \in {R^n}$ a.e., all the functions $f_s(x)$ are defined?

Tags: measure-theory

I'm trying to solve problem 18 in chapter 6 from Jone's "Lebesgue Integration on Euclidean Space" When I read the problem first, I couldn't understand some condition in this problem.

Some statements in problem 18 from from Jone's "Lebesgue Integration on Euclidean Space" :

Suppose that for any $s \in R$, there is given a measurable function $f_s$ defined a.e.
"***Suppose $\lim_{s\rightarrow\infty}$ $f_s$ (x)  exists a.e., and notice that this statement requires that for $x \in {R^n}$ a.e., all the functions $f_s(x)$ are defined.***"

In case that $s \in {N}$ not $R$, I could prove that for $x \in N$ a.e., all the functions $f_s(x)$ are defined (by using that the a countable union of null sets is also a null set).
But, I couldn't find that how to show above statement in italic.

Thank you for teaching me in advance.

p.s. Sorry for typo in questions.
Changes: for $x \in {R^n}\Rightarrow $ for $x \in {R^n}$ a.e.,

Comment: The first statement in the title implies that for sufficiently large $s$ all the $f_s(x)$ are defined at $x$, since the limit must be of defined values. There's nothing different about taking $s\in R$ rather than $s\in N$.

Comment: @Kevin Carlson : Thanks for replying. I thought that for given x, there exists $S_x$ such that $f_s(x)$ are defined for $s >= S_x$., But, since x and s are uncountable, I couldn't construct a null set which contains all x such that $f_s(x)$ is not defined for some s in R.

Comment: @Kevin Carlson : Could you give me more hints?

Comment: There's nothing excluding that e.g. $f_s$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{s\}$. Then for every $S$, the set $\left\{x\in\mathbb{R} : \bigl(\exists s > S\bigr)\bigl(f_s \text{ is not defined at } x\bigr)\right\}$ has infinite measure.

Comment: Of course, the author may have the convention that the existence of $\lim\limits_{s\to\infty} f_s(x)$ implies the definedness of $f_s(x)$ for all $s$. Then the assertion is trivial.

Comment: @DanielFischer : Thank you for answering my question. After reading your hint, I thought that the intersection of {x $/in$ R:(∃ s>S) ($f_s$ is not defined at x)} is a null set by assumption that $lim_{s-> \intfy}$ $f_s(x)$ exists a.e., and for all x in the complement of this null set, all the functions $f_s(x)$ are defined by construction of this null set.

Comment: I couldn't convince myself that I totally understand hints given in this question. But, thanks everyone for giving ideas or hints.